# How to get a desired key from user within a TextBox and use it in Keyboard.isKeyDown(Key." ... ")

Tags: c#

I just start C# and I wanted to make a Form App which gets a key from user, within the TextBox, then somehow bind that key and with SendKeys(), spam a specific key that I set in codes e.g(e), I use this code but the `Keyboard.isKeyDown(Key.key)` wants me an enum of "Key" and TexBox returns a string and even I converted the string to an enum but it just want me a key from its own `Key` enum, my question is how to pass a variable key to the `Keyboard.isKeyDown(Key.key)` maybe totally my way is not right, can you help me with these codes or suggest another way to make this app?

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread TH = new Thread(PressBind);
            TH.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            TH.Start();
        }

        //i want to get the key from this textbox

        public void TxBxKTB_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label2.Text = $"The binded key is : {TxBxKTB.Text.ToString()}";
            TextBox objTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
            string text = objTextBox.Text;
            var TextBoxText = Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), text);
        }

        //void setforground()
        //{
        //    IntPtr Calculator = FindWindow("Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow", "Calculator");
        //    SetForegroundWindow(Calculator);
        //}

        bool isRunning = true;

        void Keyboard()
        {
            while (isRunning)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(40);
                if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.I want to set the users input key here))
                {
                    label1.Text = "pressed";
                    Thread.Sleep(40);
                    SendKeys.SendWait("e");
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            isRunning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, are you trying to find a way to switch a key pressed by a user for some other key of your choosing?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils - Yes somehow, actually i want to make an app that user set a key in textbox then user hit the BIND button and whenever the user hit his desired key in a programm it spams e.g "e" word. i wonder how to pass a variable key to the IsKeyDown(Key." ... ").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### UPDATE

You could use [Enum.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse) method to convert string to `Key` enum. It's safer to use `TryParse` to handle situations when string can't be converted to `Key`.

```
void Z()
{
    string key_string = "F10";
    if (Enum.TryParse(key_string, out Key key))
    {
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(key))
        {
            // some logic
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // ERROR: the string couldn't be converted to Key
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an explanation alongside of your code?

Comment: There's nothing to explain: the text representation of a key as a string is being converted to `Key` enum - that's all! 

Comment: Fair enough :) I mainly asked because I thought the `Enum.Parse` was new for OP but I just overlooked it in their code.

Comment: @Joelius Updated answer. 

Comment: @JohnyL - I changed the codes according to what u said, and i faced into a new problem that i said above.

Comment: @SeyyedMahdiHoseini Your code is fine. The problem could lie in incorrect string key. And to spot a problem, use `TryParse` code (as in my answer) to see, whether parsing was successful.

Comment: @JohnyL - I use your codes but the arguments place was incorrect in (typeof(Key), key_string, out object key)) and i just change that
but totally nothing happened, the lable didnt change,  i use your codes like above... did i use it correctly? or i should call the Z() method in form_load?

Comment: @SeyyedMahdiHoseini You should use: if (Enum.TryParse(key_string, out _object_ key)), but you're using `Key`

Comment: @JohnyL - Right but it didnt accept object and i change that into Key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195745/discussion-between-johnyl-and-seyyed-mahdi-hoseini).